# ModuleNotFoundError when using pip install in Docker build

Tags: docker, build, pip, dockerfile, requirements.txt

So, I came across many threads talking about this specific issue but was unable to really find the suitable fix for me.

I have the following requirements summarised in a requirements.txt file in my root directory

```
stripe==2.51.0
bottle==0.12.18
```

My src/app.py starts as

```py
from bottle import route, run, template, get, post, request, response, static_file
import stripe

# rest of the code I assume isn't relevant
```

I'm using a Dockerfile to build an image as follows:

```
#  build 1
FROM python:3.8.5 AS builder
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt

# build 2
FROM python:3.8.5-slim
COPY --from=builder /root/.local/bin /root/.local
COPY ./src .

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PATH=/root/.local:$PATH
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

Even though I used `--user` alongside adding the root path to my final path, I still end up with the following error :

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle'
```

I'm also - I think - using the same interpreter when it comes to installing my packages and running them so I don't really know how to troubleshoot this.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes:

```
COPY --from=builder /root/.local /root/.local
```

```
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Suggestion: use `slim-buster`, your Dockerfile could end like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-slim-buster AS base

FROM base AS builder
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt

FROM base AS release
COPY --from=builder /root/.local /root/.local
COPY ./src .
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Was able to download

```
stripe==2.51.0
bottle==0.12.18
```

with the given dockerfile and requirements.txt.

Put the Dockerfile and requirements.txt in same folder and install docker-desktop in your local machine and run " docker build ." from that folder in cmd which would provide with locally building the docker image.
Log received:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.8.5 AS builder
3.8.5: Pulling from library/python
d6ff36c9ec48: Pull complete
c958d65b3090: Pull complete
edaf0a6b092f: Pull complete
80931cf68816: Pull complete
7dc5581457b1: Pull complete
87013dc371d5: Pull complete
dbb5b2d86fe3: Pull complete
4cb6f1e38c2d: Pull complete
0b3d7b2fc317: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d21be681213425a9a0b736f62b218dad823789a5c708543fbad284b0c06f62a5
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.8.5
 ---> 62aa40094bb1
Step 2/9 : COPY requirements.txt .
 ---> e6ea6fe42122
Step 3/9 : RUN python -m pip install --user -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in b9ea44bb9f44
Collecting stripe==2.51.0
  Downloading stripe-2.51.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (203 kB)
Collecting bottle==0.12.18
  Downloading bottle-0.12.18-py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.20; python_version >= "3.0"
  Downloading requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
```

Try also updating the docker file as
Dockerfile

```
# build 2
FROM python:3.8.5-slim
ADD requirements.txt /
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt
COPY ./src .   #### 

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PATH=/root/.local:$PATH ###not sure of the use####
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

Comment: Yeah the warning would not happen at build time, rather when trying to actually run the container. Have you tried running it ?

Comment: do you have sample app.py for reference,to run in docker